# How to access parent object fields fron child object instance in wrapper class in salesforce?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, wrapper-class

`Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c`(Child) having lookup to (Parent)Proposal obj(`Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c`).

```
private class xyz{
        public Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c objProposalLineItemRecord;
        public String strMainBundleCode;
        public String strArcadiaBundleCode;
        public Boolean validForConversion;
        public Boolean isArcadiaOption;
        public String productLevelCOorSLI;
        public xyz(Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c currentRecord, String masterBundleCode, String arcadiaBundleCode, Boolean isValid, String coORsliLevel, Boolean arcadiaOption){
            objProposalLineItemRecord = currentRecord;
            strMainBundleCode = masterBundleCode;
            strArcadiaBundleCode = arcadiaBundleCode;
            validForConversion = isValid;
            productLevelCOorSLI = coORsliLevel;
            isArcadiaOption = arcadiaOption;
        }
    }
```

---

```
xyz newInstanceWrapper = new xyz(
    new Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c(
        Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c =objLineItem.Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c,
        Apttus_QPConfig__Quantity2__c=QDSIArcadiaOptions.Quantity__c, 
        Total_Option_Quantity__c = QDSIArcadiaOptions.Quantity__c,
        Apttus_QPConfig__LineType__c='option',
        Item_Type_From_CAT__c =QDSIArcadiaOptions.Item_Type__c,
        Apttus_QPConfig__OptionId__c = mapPrdCodeANDPrdID.get(QDSIArcadiaOptions.Product_Code__c),
        Apttus_Proposal__Product__c = mapPrdCodeANDPrdID.get(QDSIArcadiaOptions.Arcadia_Product_Code__c),
        Apttus_QPConfig__LineNumber__c = QDSIArcadiaOptions.Parent_Line_Item__r.Apttus_Config2__LineNumber__c
    ), 
    strMainBundelProdCode, 
    arcadiaBundleCode, 
    false, 
    Test, 
    true
);
```

When trying to access

```
String Name = xyz.objProposalLineItemRecord.Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__r.Name;
```

getting null in Name.

Comment: What you have tried so far and where are you stuck? Can you paste your code here?

Comment: @rahulgawale  :When trying to access 
  String Name = objOrderExportWrapper.objProposalLineItemRecord.Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__r.Name;
  getting null in Name.

Comment: Check if you have that value before passing it to the wrapper, How are you setting this `currentRecord`, is this a queried or newly created?

Comment: @rahulgawale: Yes i checked i have Id of parent or not before getting value of Name , i am getting lookup id ,but when trying to access any other field (for ext Name : getting null). I am trying to create new rec (not queried) instance in wrapper  by passing value in constructure.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access

```
xyz.objProposalLineItemRecord.Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__r.Name
```

because you are not populating an sObject instance in `Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__r`. You're populating an sObject Id in `Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c`. This does not provide you with access to related-record fields:

```
xyz newInstanceWrapper = new xyz(
new Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c(
    Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c =objLineItem.Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c,
```

You'd need to set `Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c = objLineItem.Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__r`, in which case you'd get access to whatever fields you queried on `Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__r` when you first retrieved `objLineItem`.

Comment: @DavisReed : if you will observer in wrapper class constructure i haved used Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c =objLineItem.Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c, its means i have linked my child obj with parent object; Later when i am trying to access Name field using String Name = xyz.objProposalLineItemRecord.Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__r.Name; am getting null in Name.

Comment: @Nikhil Yes, I understand that. My answer is attempting to explain why that doesn't work.

Comment: @Davis : Ok, Thanks a lot for attemptting, I replied to make it more clear.